# Stripping unwanted characters from a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a library called kanren (https://github.com/logpy/logpy#kanren). It uses the eq operator and returns a numerical value in the following format: (3,). I want to take the integer value only and put it into an if statement. Is there a way I can use only the 3 from the above example? Is this parsing or could I use the re library or something else?

Answer (score 0):

(3,) is a tuple, you can get its int value by `tuple_var[0]`

Here is and example.

```
tuple_var = (3,)
print(tuple_var[0])
>>> 3
```

here's some reading in that subject https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax

hope it helps.